Magento 2 : get source inventory after product is saved if quantity was changed
Magento 2, How to get source inventory after product is saved, if quantity was changed or stock status was changed.

In Magento 2, if you want to get the source inventory after a product is saved, specifically when the quantity or stock status is changed, you can use the catalog_product_save_after event. This event allows you to perform custom logic after a product is saved, including checking the stock status and inventory.
Here's how you can implement this functionality:
Step 1: Create a Custom Module

Create the Module Structure:
First, create a new module. Let's use Vendor/InventoryCheck as an example.
app/code/Vendor/InventoryCheck/


Create registration.php:
In app/code/Vendor/InventoryCheck/registration.php:
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_InventoryCheck',
    __DIR__
);


Create module.xml:
In app/code/Vendor/InventoryCheck/etc/module.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_InventoryCheck" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>



Step 2: Create an Observer

Create an Event Observer:
Create events.xml in app/code/Vendor/InventoryCheck/etc/:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="vendor_inventory_check_observer" instance="Vendor\InventoryCheck\Observer\InventoryObserver" />
    </event>
</config>


Create the Observer Class:
Create the observer class InventoryObserver.php in app/code/Vendor/InventoryCheck/Observer/:
<?php

namespace Vendor\InventoryCheck\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface;

class InventoryObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $productFactory;
    protected $sourceRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        SourceRepositoryInterface $sourceRepository
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->sourceRepository = $sourceRepository;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        // Check if the stock status or quantity has changed
        if ($product->hasData('stock_data')) {
            $stockData = $product->getData('stock_data');
            $isInStock = isset($stockData['is_in_stock']) ? $stockData['is_in_stock'] : null;
            $qty = isset($stockData['qty']) ? $stockData['qty'] : null;

            // Perform logic based on the stock status and quantity
            if ($isInStock !== null || $qty !== null) {
                // Fetch the source inventory
                $this->getSourceInventory($product->getId());
            }
        }
    }

    private function getSourceInventory($productId)
    {
        // Implement your logic to get source inventory
        $sources = $this->sourceRepository->getList();

        // Process and retrieve source inventory
        foreach ($sources->getItems() as $source) {
            // Here you can get the inventory data for each source
            // Example: echo $source->getName();
            // Add your logic here
        }
    }
}



Step 3: Enable and Test the Module

Enable the Module:
After creating all the necessary files, enable the module and clear the cache:
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_InventoryCheck
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush



Explanation of the Code

Event Listener: The catalog_product_save_after event is triggered after a product is saved, allowing you to execute custom logic.
Observer Class: In the execute method, we check if the stock status (is_in_stock) or quantity (qty) has changed by accessing the stock_data of the product.
Source Inventory: The getSourceInventory method fetches the source inventory data. You can extend this method to include whatever logic you need to retrieve and manipulate the source inventory.

Final Thoughts
This implementation allows you to effectively track changes to product stock status and quantity after saving, enabling you to fetch and utilize the relevant source inventory as needed. Adjust the logic in the getSourceInventory method to suit your specific requirements. If you have any further questions or need more help, feel free to ask!
